# IPython in Emacs py-shell: TAB completion not working & windows get killed

Tags: shell, emacs, ipython, tab-completion

I've switched from ipython 0.10-11.1 to 1.1.0

Now, using Emacs together with the new ipython version I run into the following two problems:

**1)** Tab completion in Emac's ipython py-shell (`C-c !`) stopped working for me. Say, if I try to complete 'pl' into 'plot' and so `pl<Tab>`, the only thing I get in the minibuffer is

```
Can't find completion for "pl" based on line pl
```

There are many similar reports about this on the web, however none of the fixes I found solve the issue for me. In particular the additions to `~/.emacs/init.el` suggested at [http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs, in section IPython just don't 'do' anything.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs)

**2)** When I start the py-shell on a any given buffer foo.py, which is open within one of several Emacs subwindows, then, all other subwindows, except for the one corresponding to foo.py and the newly started (ipython) py-shell get closed.

Both of these issues where absent in ipython 0.10-11.1. Anyone has an idea?

My Emacs version: GNU Emacs 23.2.1. My ipython.el version: defconst ipython-version "0.11" from https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/docs/emacs

Answer (score 0):

Completion from a (I)Python-shell is just <kbd>TAB</kbd>

<kbd>C-c !</kbd> from inside a shell should open another shell, but seems broken indeed, resp. it's not available.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1234539
Fixed in trunk meanwhile.

BTW to open a second shell from inside, <kbd>C-u M-x python</kbd> should work.

Did you set `py-python-command-args` accordingly?
Assume `plot` needs option `-pylab`.

Troubleshooting:

Start with Emacs -Q from the directory where python-mode.el lives.
Open python-mode.el and evaluate it.

Open a --maybe empty-- file with ending ".py".

Python-mode should be switched on.

M-x python RET

a regular Python-shell should appear.

M-x ipython RET

an IPython-shell should open.

Always call (I)Python-shell from a python-mode activated already.
Otherwise shipped python.el or other stuff might come between.

Link shows TAB-completion with IPython-1.1.0 at work:

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/152211804/ex.png

Comment: (i) I followed your troubleshooting remarks. Once I have the IPython-shell open and do TAB-completion on any incomplete word, this word gets replaced on the same input line by "Traceback (most recent call last):". Any idea what this means? (ii) the image for TAB-completion with IPython-1.1.0 at work looks exactly as it was for me before 1.1.0

Comment: (iii) Finally, I also applied your troubleshooting procedure to the 2nd part of my question, i.e., that invoking the python shell kills all other open windows in Emacs - and also that remains the same. Is this proper? Can I suppress that?

Comment: @Mark Please let know us, what the IPython-process responded, i.e. give the Traceback. Please consider to open a ticket at launchpad.net/python-mode for that.

Comment: @Mark (iii) Windows behavior is controlled by settings of py-split-windows-on-execute-p resp. py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p. If both are nil, shell should run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer does not provide any clue for how to get <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion to work with IPython-1.1.0 and GNU Emacs 23.2.1. In fact the troubleshooting steps, starting from a bare-bones Emacs, do not lead to an IPython-shell with working <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion. Moreover the image at https://launchpadlibrarian.net/152211804/ex.png claiming <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion at work with IPython-1.1.0 depicts an Emacs 24.3.50.1, rather than an Emacs 23.2.1 which I was referring to in my question.

For me **the solution was**: get rid of IPython-1.1.0 reinstall IPython 0.10-11.1.

(That leaves you without the more recent notebook feature - which is fine if Emacs is at the core of your Python workflow anyway)

Comment: python-mode.el is tested with Emacs-23.4 also. There was no hint so far an earlier version shouldn't work. Please consider to give a more detailed bug report WRT the state when failing.